# Why do I get an HTML page as a response when using Access Token and the desired result when using ID Token? (Azure AD)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, access-token, bearer-token

When I **successfully** login through my Web API with my **Azure AD** credentials, I receive the ID & Access Token.

I understood that a best practice to consume a Web API is to use an Access Token instead of an ID Token.

In Postman I use ID Token and can Access all data where Authorization is required.
When using the Access Token to consume the API, I get a **Microsoft HTML login** page and a **200 OK Status**

```
<!-- Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" class="" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Sign in to your account</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0, user-scalable=yes">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://aadcdn.msftauth.net" crossorigin>
    <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="on">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msftauth.net">
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//aadcdn.msauth.net">

    <meta name="PageID" content="ConvergedSignIn" />
    <meta name="SiteID" content="" />
    <meta name="ReqLC" content="1033" />
    <meta name="LocLC" content="en-US" />

    <meta name="referrer" content="origin" />

    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=https://login.microsoftonline.com/jsdisabled" />
    </noscript>
...
```

Comment: You cannot use an ID token to access the API, the ID token will just contain user information that you can use to authorize it or some other things like getting the user's department, etc. 
Looks like what you are getting is what Postman would show by default when you request a token againts login.microsoftonline.com that requires user interaction, as postman will not prompt for credentials
Can you paste the API call you are doing in order to get that response ?

Comment: This is impossible. I don't think you can use id token to call api. Please provide your detailed operation process.

Comment: Yes, it may sound strange but I use the ID Token to consume the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could consume the Web API by using the ID-token with all token validation parameters set to false - in services.AddAuthentication... *Startup.cs*.

I changed some Token Validation Parameters to true. I also use AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword to generate valid Access Tokens from Graph API:

```
IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in user.Password.ToCharArray())  // fetch the password
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

var tokens = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, user.UserName, securePassword).ExecuteAsync().Result;

_graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(x =>
    {
        x.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", tokens.AccessToken);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
```